# Why does gensim LdaMulticore produce different results on different machines?

Tags: python, multithreading, nlp, gensim, lda

**Why does gensim Lda Multicore produce different results on different machines?**

How do I calibrate LdaMulticore parameters on different machines/machine-specific?

This is why I ask: I run gensim on 2 different machines (Windows PC; gensim                    3.8.3 and Linux Cluster; gensim 4.1.2).

a) it returns good results for the machine A (Windows PC Thinkpad X11 Yoga - coherence increases, perplexity decreases).

b) it returns not so good results for machine B (Linux Cluster 40 cores, coherence increases but perplexity increases as well and the topics are not well distanced)

The perplexity and coherence on both machines compare as follows (thank you @gojomo for your suggestion):

[image: coherence score]

[image: perplexity score]

I run it with the configuration, as uploaded on github here:

[github for LDA](https://github.com/rolandbaatz/LDA_for_research/blob/main/1_model_selection.ipynb)

Main LDA call is:

```
        lda_model = LdaMulticore(corpus=corpus,
             id2word=id2word,
             num_topics=topics,
            #            eval_every=20,
            chunksize=300,
             passes=50,
             iterations=100,
            random_state=100,
            per_word_topics=True)
```

Comment: It's hard to contrast the two charts as all three of their axes have different ranges, in the same amount of visual space. I suggest one graph comparing perplexity between the two, one comparing coherence, with both having an identical range of number-of-topics.

Comment: Thank you gojomo, I updated the charts, and added the full code to call LDA. I'd be greatful for your help on this.

Comment: In the documentation (https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamulticore.html) it states at the description of `random_state` : "Note that results can still vary due to non-determinism in OS scheduling of the worker processes".  The multiple cores are not used in the same sequence and therefore the different data chunks are in a different random state. Have you tried a sequential run and compared the results then? In that case, the results should be the same.

Comment: No, I did not try. I understand random refers to Topics and it would not refer to performance, convergence and perplexity. I will give it a try.

Comment: OK. The package version creates this deviation. I upgraded to v.4.2.0 on PC and run LDAMulticore, and now log_perplexity increases with gensim 4.2.0 just as it is the case for the HPC. Decreasing log_perplexity is desirable, while the results seem fine even though log_perplexity increases. As far as I can tell, perplexity is very close to zero. Can I go with these results then?

Comment: Thanks for clearer charts! Though, previously, didn't numbers for one alternative go up past 30 topics? (Do the trends continue out of shown range?) Ultimately, training runs on these sorts of models are subject to lots of run-to-run randomness, even with exact same system/params, but which should generally result in models of similar *utility* at end (especially once data/parameters are sufficient), even if the particulars vary a little. If the 'jitter' between runs results in final models of wildly-different quality, not just little diffs, there may be other data/parameterization problems.

Comment: More generally, spreading a training task over multiple independent processes can help eliminate one bottleneck – by using more processing power – but by necessarily introducing another: communication overhead, as replicas/shards need to keep each other informed of latest progress. It's plausible that a training job run on very-different process-count & syncronization-overhead will have tangibly different results, or require different parameters (especially perhaps, more `passes`) to reach convergence.)

Comment: I'd suggest: evaluate effects of choices like Gensim version, system/OS, & count of `workers` vary narrowly, one-at-a-time, without letting `workers` also vary based on underlying system. That is: specify `workers` to be one less than the smaller machine's number of physical cores both places, so you're comparing like-to-like. Then, separately, on the machine that has more cores, try a range of `workers` values up to its max, to independently understand the effect of that parameter on your desired end-measures.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the responses.
Yes, I estimated up to 30 topics. Trends remained stable. I stopped with 19 topics now, for saving computational time.

Gensim version (3.8 vs. 4.1+) caused the different behaviour in perplexity metric as result of the LDAMultiCore.After updating Gensim 3.8 to 4.2, perplexity metric for PC resulted in about the same as for the HPC.

The calibration measures suggested in the comments, might be useful to fellow LdaMulticore analysts. As I now obtained models of similar utility, I am satisfied with the results. Identified topics remain stable - independent of LDA specific parameters or of the machine. Althought the log_perplexity increases, the coherence score also increases as in the HPC results. Coherence seems to be the more important measure here to produce reasonable outcomes.

Cheers